# Nested python decorator?

Tags: python, decorator

I don't know if "Nested python decorator?" is the right way to state this question, so let me know if it's not.

Anyway, I'm taking a class at udacity and have just encountered some code that involves python decorator and looks like voodoo magic, so now I want to ask a generalized question to see if I can figure that code out.

Suppose that I have the following code:

```
def A(f):
    print 'blah'
    return f

@A
def B(f):
    return f

@B
def C():
    pass
```

Now, I understand that from the above code, the decorator causes B to turn into:

```
B = A(B)
```

and that's what a decorator does. However, what is C like?
From some small sample codes I have seen, somehow C is affected by A because A changes B and B changes C. But I have two problems understanding this:

1. The exact nature of C. Is it `C = A(B)(C)` or `C = A(B(C))`?
2. If C is indeed affected by A, why is 'blah' only printed once when I run the above code?

**Personal guess**

Actually, now that I have typed it out, I hypothesize that what happens is we first get:
`B = A(B)` and *then* `C = B(C)`. It means that overall, we get `C = A(B)(C)`, and it would explain why 'blah' is only printed once.

But it's best that I make sure.

Comment: Your decorators aren't actually doing anything to the decorated function, so your second example is equivalent to `B = B` and your third example is the same as `C = C`. (There is a side effect of printing something, but that doesn't affect the function.)

Comment: Yea, I know that. It's just meant to be a general question, and that's easier to write. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your personal guess is correct.

A decorator is "called" at definition-time, when the `@`-line and its following function definition are evaluated.

```
@foo
def bar():
    pass
```

is just syntactic sugar for...

```
def bar():
    pass
bar = foo(bar)
```

Comment: Hmm, it seems that I was overthinking this. Now it just feels like "How did I get stuck in the first place?" Thank you for your help. :)